# Sprite not moving consistently

Tags: pygame, sprite

I am trying to make a game in pygame, I have a character, a sprite, that moves when I push the arrow keys. The problem is that when I move constantly up then down the sprite slowly moves upwards. I dont know if that makes sense but basically I move a sprite 700/12 pixels up and then back down but after I move it back down it ends up slightly higher than before.

```
`   if direction == "up":
        character.rect.bottom -= 700/12
    elif direction == "down":
        character.rect.bottom += 700/12
    elif direction == "left":
        character.rect.x -= 700/12
    elif direction == "right":
        character.rect.x += 700/12`
```

Comment: Does Pygame even support non-integer coordinates?  You're adding/subtracting a fractional value, if the result is being rounded towards zero each time this will accumulate.  Example: start at 100, add 58.33 = 158.33, round down = 158, subtract 58.33 = 99.67, round down = 99.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that is because you're using `bottom` rather than `y`.  The sprite's `(x,y)` refers to the top-left corner, whereas `bottom` refers to `y` + `height`. That would give a subtle movement difference.

Simply changing the updated member should fix it:

```
if direction == "up":
    character.rect.y -= 700/12   # <-- HERE, y not bottom
elif direction == "down":
    character.rect.y += 700/12   # <-- HERE, y not bottom
...
```

Comment: would it really matter? I will try it but bottom is just the lowest y coordinate, and it is not like I use different words in different places, I use bottom for both.

Comment: @banana - Well I did say "suspect", it was the best I could come up with, given just 8 lines of code ;)

Comment: I wasnt trying to be rude, I was just asking. I appreciate everyone's help. I found the error though, the problem was that I was subtracting and adding one third which I guess python rounds weirdly because when I changed it to another number it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was trying to subtract and add 1/3 to my y coord which was rounded off weirdly, because after changing it to a different int it worked fine